# SwiftUI handling SpriteKit scene recreation when data changes

Tags: core-data, sprite-kit, swiftui

I have a `SwiftUI` view that is connected to a `CoreData` model. I also have a `SpriteKit` scene that changes data in my model. So every time I manipulate my data from my SKScene in CoreData my scene gets reinitialised which is an unwanted behaviour in my case.

How can I get the updated model in my `SpriteView` without the `SKScene` being recreated?

My code looks like this:

```
struct TamagotchiListView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext

@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: TamagotchiModel.getFetchRequest())
var tamagotchis: FetchedResults<TamagotchiModel>

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(tamagotchis, id: \.self) { (tamagotchi: TamagotchiModel) in
                NavigationLink(destination: SpriteKitView(scene: SpriteKitScene(model: tamagotchi))) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "gamecontroller")
                            .padding(.trailing, 5)
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(tamagotchi.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                            Spacer()
                            Text(tamagotchi.birthDate, style: .date)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is needed some kind of reproducible example to avoid guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around my problem by creating a view model that manages the SpriteKit scene creation if needed.

```
class TamagotchiViewModel {
    
    private var spriteKitScenes: [SpriteKitScene] = []
    
    func scene(for tamagotchi: TamagotchiModel) -> SpriteKitScene {
        if let scene = spriteKitScenes.first(where: { $0.tamagotchi?.tamagotchiModel.id == tamagotchi.id}) {
            return scene
        } else {
            let newScene = SpriteKitScene(model: tamagotchi)
            spriteKitScenes.append(newScene)
            return newScene
        }
    }
}
```